# Rspec expect to receive with anything as param

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can I expect a receiver to receive some arguments, which I only care about matching some of the arguments?

```rb
expect(Service).to receive(:foo).with(anything, "must-match", anything).and_return(response)
```

Comment: It's not worked for you?

Comment: You can also use the block form of `receive` - see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#use-a-block-to-verify-arguments